# Using a jquery plugin in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a jQuery plugin in jQuery code. The plugin is for filtering the table data. The demo of plugin can be found [here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Multi-column-Table-Sorting-Filtering-Dynamitable/).

Now, I want to use the plugin with a table created in jQuery. I am trying to add the plugin using `addClass()` method and `attr()` method. But it's not working. I don't know how to use the plugin in my code.

```
<script>
$('#filter_table').append('<table>').addClass("js-dynamitable").append('<thead>');

    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        $('#filter_table').append( '<tr>');
        if(i==0)
        {
            $('#filter_table').append( '<th style="color: red;"> Name <span class="js-sorter-desc"></span> <span class="js-sorter-asc"></span> </th>');
            $('#filter_table').append( '<th style="color: red;"> Email <span class="js-sorter-desc"></span> <span class="js-sorter-asc"></span> </th>');
            $('#filter_table').append( '<th style="color: red;"> Age <span class="js-sorter-desc"></span> <span class="js-sorter-asc"></span></th>');
        }
        else if(i==1)
        {
            $('#filter_table').append( '<th> <input>').attr('class','js-filter');
            $('#filter_table').append('</th>');
            $('#filter_table').append( '<th> <select class="js-filter"> <option value=""></option> <option value="@gmail.com">Gmail</option> <option value="@yahoo.com">Yahoo</option> <option value="@rediff.com">Rediff</option> </select></th>');
            $('#filter_table').append( '<th> <input  class="js-filter" type="text" value=""> </th>');
        }
        $('#filter_table').append('</tr>');
    }
    $('#filter_table').append('</thead> <tbody>');
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        $('#filter_table').append( '<tr>');

        {
            $('#filter_table').append( '<td> Rohit </td>');
            $('#filter_table').append( '<td> Rohit@gmail.com </td>');
            $('#filter_table').append( '<td> 18 </td>');
        }
        $('#filter_table').append('</tr>');
        $('#filter_table').append('<tr>');
        {
            $('#filter_table').append( '<td> Ryan </td>');
            $('#filter_table').append( '<td> Ryan123@yahoo.com </td>');
            $('#filter_table').append( '<td> 32 </td>');
        }
        $('#filter_table').append('</tr>');
    }
    $('#filter_table').append('</tbody></table>');  
    </script>
```

Comment: My guess would be the plugin doesn't see the dynamically added class. but I also didn't bother looking at the plugin docs/source.

Comment: I have added "js-filter" class in **"$('#filter_table').append( '<th> <input>').attr('class','js-filter');** . I wanted to add that class to input tag but it has been added to "filter_table". Can u tell me how to add a class to a particular tag??

Comment: you add a class to a tag using the addclass method... that's not relevant to what i was saying. For all i know the plugin could be looking for said class on dom ready, and then never again.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$('#filter_table').append('<table><thead>');
$('#filter_table').addClass("js-dynamitable");
```

instead of

```
$('#filter_table').append('<table>').addClass("js-dynamitable").append('<thead>')
```